# "logistically very difficult" phrase

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

Does the phrase "*logistically very difficult*" sound correct in the following fragment?

> Given that it would be logistically very difficult to conduct the experiment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase "*logistically very difficult*" sounds fine, but depending on the context you might also use,

> Given that conducting the experiment is [impractical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impractical), …

or

> Given that conducting the experiment is not [feasible](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feasible), …

Since when you're describing an experiment as *feasible*, it would be  generally understood that you're referring to the feasibility of conducting the experiment, you could probably simplify this to:

> Given that the experiment is not feasible, …

Also note, you could replace "*not feasible*" with "[*infeasible*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/infeasible)", but that's a much less common word.

Answer (score 3):

It is grammatically fine.

It's semantically fine if the experiment would in fact involve logistics: coordinating people, processes and delivery of resources across a broad geographic area.

People misuse "logistics" nowadays as a synonym for "practicality", "feasibility" or "complexity", which it isn't.

It's also not related to "logic" or that work's Greek root "logos" at all; rather, it's related to the word "lodge" and its etymology.

See here: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=logistics

Comment: @FranciscoC Yes, so for instance if there isn't any problem obtaining the equipment and other materials for the experiment, but it requires a lot of patience and skill, and takes numerous coordinated steps, then it's not really a problem of logistics.